# Can I rename a public group without it messing up any sharing rules, triggers, etc.?

Tags: public

I'm simply renaming a public group and want to make sure it's not impacting anything else. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Sharing rules, etc use the Id of the group internally to keep track of the group, so there's no risk of screwing up most declarative metadata. However, Flows and Apex could query the Group record by name, so changing the name may break Flows and Apex (Triggers, Visualforce, etc). It can also screw up your Git repository if you're tracking your metadata in such a repository. Make sure you check your org's documentation, as there is definitely a non-zero risk of damaging things.